# How to define template template types with inheritance in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I would like to define a derived class that has a template template type for a templated base class.  Is this possible, and if so what is the syntax?  I have tried a lot of things without success.  Please consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename U>
struct Wrapper {};

template <typename U>
struct Base {};

// This Works, define a template template type class
template<class>
struct Other;
template<template<typename T> typename W, typename T>
struct Other<W<T>> {};

// How do I define this?
template<template<typename T> typename W, typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<W<T>> {};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Wrapper<float> w;
    Base<int> b;
    Other<Wrapper<int>> o;
    Derived<Wrapper<int>> d;  // fails to compile
    return 0;
}
```

Why:  I have existing/working code that has `Derived<U>` where `U` is a wrapped class `W<T>`. Specifying `Derived<W<T>>` in the definition using a template template type was unnecessary; `Derived<U>` is sufficient. Both `W` and `T` can be many different concrete types, but `T` will always have a statically available method that I now need access to from within Derived scope.

I am currently and woefully limited to C++11.

Comment: Please include the error message in the question

Comment: if you give specialized template type for template template parameter, you got compile error like this: `template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template`
change line that you marked "fails to compile" to `Derived<Wrapper, int> d;` then it compiles. https://godbolt.org/z/759TE7674

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, things get much simpler if you realize that, for most regards, an instantiation of a class template is just a type like any other. And confusing types with templates is also the source of your error.

`Wrapper<int>` is a type. The first argument for the `Derived` template is a template, not a type.

`Other` is a template that has a single type argument. It has a partial specialization for the case that this type is an instantiation of some template `W`.

`Derived` is a template that has two arguments. The first is a template argument, the second is a type. An instantiation is, for example: `Derived<W,int>`.

If you want to make `Derived` a template with a single type argument, with a partial specialization for the case that this type is an instantiation of `Wrapper`, then you need to do the same as you did for `Other`: A base template with a single type argument and a specialization, eg:

```
template<class> struct Derived;

template<template<typename T> typename W, typename T> 
struct Derived<W<T>> : public Base<W<T>> {};
```

The second line is the partial specialization. It does not change the fact that `Derived` has one type argument. It only makes `Derived<W<T>>` match this specialization no matter what `T` is.